# Origins of the 'editorial we' and its counterpart, the 'editorial I'

Tags: pronouns, history, historical-change, convention, journalism

In researching an unrelated EL&U answer, I came across this commentary in an item titled "[Hobart Town](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/2193825?searchTerm=%22speaking%20in%20the%20first%20person%20singular%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&searchLimits=sortby=dateAsc)" in the *Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser* (November 10, 1829):

> These three journals—the *Courier*, the *Colonial Times*, and the *Tasmanian*—are all conducted in a very respectable manner.
>
> The first made us laugh most heartily by the novel and utterly *outré* practice lately adopted by its Editor, of **speaking in the first person singular**! We believe it is without precedent or parallel in the whole history of newspapers, at least within the last hundred years ; and it looks and sounds so exquisitely odd, that it is difficult to persuade one's self the worthy Editor is not quizzing. Perhaps he has in his eye the example of the *Spectator*, and the similar diurnals of the eighteenth century : it is at all events a bold defiance of fashion and immemorial usage.

This item makes a couple of interesting points about the "editorial *we*": (1) it was (in 1829) so thoroughly established that the use of first-person singular by the editor of the *[Hobart] Courier* struck the author of this article as "novel and utterly *outré*"; and (2) its dominance as a journalistic convention was of such long standing that the author of the item could not think of a single countervailing instance "within the last hundred years."

I have two questions on this subject:

1. Assuming that the convention is not primordial, when did use of the "editorial *we*" first arise in English journalism?
2. To what extent was the *[Hobart] Courier* editor's use of the "editorial *I*" something new under the British Empire's unsetting sun, and to what extent did it reflect an earlier style perhaps discernible in Addison & Steele's *Spectator* or other early periodicals?

Comment: Too broad, too broad. Why should the question belong to English? It's purely about journalism.

Comment: I think this is a great question about [nosism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism) in English. Given that not all languages use grammatical person in the same way as English, the question cannot be answered except by reference to particular languages. If this really is purely about journalism, and occurs in many languages, that would itself go some way to answering the question.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/07/nosism.html) cites an 1829 publication which referred to “the fashionable virtue of the day in nos-ism.”

Comment: Related: [“Royal we” agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386814/royal-we-agreement) and [The Royal We: Who are “we”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336710/the-royal-we-who-are-we)

Comment: @sjy The WP article nowhere mentions English.

Comment: The late lamented *Editorial We*? "The Editorial We: A Posthumous Autobiography" https://www.amazon.com/Editorial-We-Posthumous-Autobiography/dp/B001Y0R64I

Comment: If I were you, I'd place a bounty on this question.

Comment: Sorry, sjy, but whatever else this has nothing to do with nosism. Nosism does apply to monarchs and megalomaniacs but the editorial we is specifically designed to describe a team, as opposed to any individual. Above many another thing, an editor or his lieutenant who does not distinguish between his own personal and his journal's collective opinions is failing in his duty.

For the same reasons, Mari-Lou, editorial and royal we are not the same at all.

What makes anyone think there's any such thing as an "editorial I"?

Comment: I can't give you a date or a name and I wouldn't want to. Why is it not obvious that some time after Gutenberg in the 15th Century, an author or printer or publisher or yes, perhaps an editor, realised there was a difference between his personal and his organisation's collective opinion, whose views contributed to the collective opinion notwithstanding?

I use Comment, not Answer, because I don't see why I should do such basic research.

Answer (score 6):

There is an article on this topic in the 12 July 1823 [Niles' Weekly Register](https://books.google.com/books?id=AuFGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR4&dq=editorial%20%22first%20person%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7oszb9MndAhVwzlkKHTnvBBIQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=editorial%20%22first%20person%22&f=false) (published in Baltimore, Maryland, USA), at page 289:

> "THE FIRST PERSON SINGULAR." When it was resolved to published the REGISTER, in 1811, it was determined also that it should be conducted by myself, alone—and that no other person or persons, on any pretence whatever, should prescribe, dictate or suggest, [imperatively], the insertion of one line, unless in justification of some charges, or to correct some mistakes that might be made; for to these we are all liable. In pursuance of this rather "*singular" notion*, the first number contained an article in which, when I spoke of myself, I used the "first person" *I*–to shew that it was I who wrote it, and that we should not have anything to do with the management of this paper.

...

> The use of "we," when a writer has to speak of himself, is often ridiculous in the extreme.

...

> I cannot tell why it should seem more *modest* to speak falsely, affect authority or shew subserviency, by the use of *we, we, we*—than if to tell the truth and aim at nothing beyond it, by the use of I, I, I.  At any rate, the last shall be used in the REGISTER by myself, even if there should be a partner in the concern, and the light of it be supported by the initials of my name—for my wish is, that every thing should pass for just as much as it is worth, and what it really is- and nothing more

So the *Courier* was not the only paper to use the singular.

However, the standard was to use the plural. For example [Enchiridion clericum, or the preacher's guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=CmACAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA104&dq=newspaper%20first%20person%20plural%20we&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC7cfppsrdAhVFu1kKHXazCFIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=newspaper%20first%20person%20plural%20we&f=false) (1812) says:

> *And always use the plural number*, — we

...

> Let sovereigns, speaking in the first person, use the plural number ; and let Reviewers, who exercise dominion in the empire of letters, use the plural number for the singular ; and newspaper editors likewise, to impress the public with an idea that their individual paper employs a constellation of talents, let them speak in the plural number ; but with what propriety can a preacher, addressing his congregation in his...

Answer (score 3):

The History of British Journalism, from the Foundation of the Newspaper Press in England, to the Repeal of the Stamp Act in 1855, with Sketches of Press Celebrities, With an Index – Alexander Andrews

> " The Printer to the Reader: " Courteous reader ! we had thought to
>   have given over printing our foreign avisoes, for that the licenser
>   (out of a partial affection) would not oftentimes let pass apparent
>   truth, and in other things (oftentimes) so crosse, and alter, which
>   made us weary of printing; but he being vanished^ (and that office
>   fallen upon another more understanding in these forraine affaires, and
>   as you will find more candid) we are againe (by the favour of his
>   Maiestie and the state) resolved to go on printing if we shall find
>   the world to give a better acceptation of them (than of late), by
>   their weekly buying them. It is well known these novels are well
>   esteemed in all parts of the world (but heere) by the more judicious,
>   which we can impute to no other but the discontinuance of them and
>   the uncertaine daies of publishing them, which, if the poste fail us
>   not, we shall keep a con stant day everie weeke therein, whereby
>   everie man may constantly expect them, and so we take leave. January
>   the 9th, 1640."
>
> One thing is herein to be observed — the editorial "
>   we" was already adopted by " the printer to the reader." ***The printer
>   was then, and continued long afterwards to be, the ostensible director
>   of the paper ; all letters, in the news papers of a century later,
>   being addressed " to the printer," until about 1740, when they were
>   occasionally addressed " to the author."***

It would thus seem that the practice started with printers addressing their readers. In early journalism, the printers were the directors of the publication and presumably what we call editors, today.

[history of British Journalism_Dec.1,1859 Publisher: Bentley](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=Z8JFAAAAcAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA30)